# Understanding ～かどうかだ

Tags: grammar, parsing

> 生きるか死ぬかの問題だった。
>   It was a question of life or death.
>   飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうかだった。
>   It was *a question of* whether or not there was a week's worth of water.

The only way I can make sense of this structure is to assume that 飲み水 is the subject of ある. I'm parsing it like this:

> [*問題は*]  [飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうか] [だった]

The comma, and the lack of the topic is making me think that 飲み水 should pair up with だった, but I can't make a meaningful parsing if that is the case.

I know it is common to omit the topic and I also know that commas don't serve the same grammatical purpose as they do in English. I'd just like to check that my understanding of this sentence is correct.

Comment: Could you also please confirm that 分 is pronounced ぶん in this context? Thanks.

Comment: You're spot on.  And yes, 分 is 「ぶん」 here (see [ーぶん definition 2 〔分量〕 here](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E5%88%86)).

Comment: So different people are thinking of different contexts and getting confused. What's the actual story? Partucularly, how long does he have to survive in this place?

Comment: 星の王子様ですよね？「飲み水がせいぜい一週間分あるかどうか、という状態だった」、「飲み水が、一週間分あるかないかっていうくらいの量しかなかった」→つまり飲み水がちょっとしかなかった、って意味じゃないんですかね・・

Comment: @chocolate あ、やっぱりそっちですよね…。だとしたら機械的に文頭に「問題は」を補うとかなり文意が変わっちゃいますよね…

Comment: @naruto Chocolate is right about the context. The narrator has just crash landed in the desert. I'm really confused about what the right answer is now. I'm particularly concerned that you seem to disagree with l'electeur since I hold you both in very high regard. Also, I really can't follow the subtleties of adding しかないということ or だということ to the sentence. I agree with you that he ought to know how much water he has but I'm not sure that implies that he should know whether or not it will last him a week. I wasn't expecting this question to be so controversial.

Comment: @naruto Also, could you please give me your translation of your two example sentences. I'm still a bit unclear on how they work. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370: 文頭に「問題は」を補う解釈は間違いと言う点ではコメントを書いた大半の人は同意しているようですが、**水が少ない**という解釈は間違いだと私は思います。「少ない」という形容詞は、ある基準に対して言うものであって、１週間程度の水が「多いか少ないか」は水の分量だけからは判断できません。読者としては１週間程度の水では大変だなという同情の気持ちは分かります。しかし、それでは１か月程度の水であったとしても気持ちは同じでしょう。「飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうかだった。」の意味は、「飲み水が、だいたい一週間分の量だった。」と言っているのに過ぎません。文脈は分かりませんが、「分かっているのは飲み水があるということ。その分量は１週間分程度であること。」「辺りを見回しても何もない。どこに居るのかすら分からない。この先どうなるのだろうか。」言い換えると、「確かなのは水が１週間分あるということだけ。それ以外は全く分からない。」と主人公が不安な中で考えているのだと推察します。

Comment: @user3856370 It's never a problem if water will last for a week per se, even if you follow l'electeur's interpretation (judging from how he translated it as "it's at the level").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conclusion first, the *grammatical* topic of the second sentence is **not** 問題(は). I know this is unusual, but in this case, adding 問題は at the beginning of the sentence will dramatically change the meaning of the original sentence!

> 1. 飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかだった。
>      There was at most only a week's worth of drinking water. / There was drinking water that might or might not last for a week. / There was some drinking water, but I was not sure it would last even for a week.
> 2. **問題は**飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかだった。
>      The problem was whether or not there was a week's worth of drinking water.

I think you already know how the second interpretation works. ～かどうか forms an embedded question, "whether or not ～". I was initially unaware of this, but the second interpretation would also be perfectly valid in a certain context. For example, if he knows he will be rescued after a week, and if he has everything to survive other than drinking water, then the only problem left is whether or not there is enough water for the next seven days.

But the actual story is not like that, and that's why you asked this question, right? :) Perhaps he had no idea when he would be rescued; he might have to wait much longer than a week. Thus the correct interpretation is **1**, and you must not add 問題は at the beginning for this sentence to work. You have to be able to interpret this sentence as-is, without adding 問題は.

So, how does the first sentence work?

～かどうかだ or ～かどうかです has a usage that is a bit different from "whether or not ～". This is a little colloquial and I don't know how to normally translate this, but the basic idea is something like "may or may not", "fifty-fifty chance", "not certain yet", "depends on chance", "on the borderline between success and failure", or such.

Some examples:

> - ここから富士山は見えるかどうかです。
>     From here, you can see Mt. Fuji if you are lucky. / Sometimes we can barely see Mt. Fuji from here. / There is a chance we can see Mt. Fuji from here.
> - 彼は合格できるかどうかです。
>     He is on the borderline between pass and fail.
> - 急いでいるが、間に合うかどうかだ。
>     I'm in a hurry, but I may or may not be able to arrive on time.

Sorry for the loose translation, but I hope you now understand how to interpret the original sentence without adding an imaginary topic.

Finally, if we do need to start this sentence with 問題は without largely changing the original meaning, we can say this:

> 問題は[飲み水が一週間分あるかどうか**だということ**]だった。
>   The problem was the fact that I had only a week's worth of drinking water (at most).

I simply enclosed the "かどうか" part with a nominalizer(?) だということ.

---

(EDIT history: Rewrote almost everything, but my opinion is the same. I hope I have explained this issue better now.)

Comment: Even if you interpret that the second sentence is under the topic of 問題, you can still interpret 一週間分あるかどうか as (an expression for shortness of) confirmed amount beside your interpretation. So, the second sentence can be either under 問題は or as its own.

Comment: @user4092 Then I think the second sentence has to be something like 「問題は飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかしかないということだった」 or 「問題は飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかだということだった」. These mean he already confirmed he had little water. I believe 「問題は飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかだった」 can be interpreted only in one way (he doesn't know the amount of water).

Comment: Certainly, omitting ということ makes it clumsy, but I'm not sure if it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @user4092 Omitting it will drastically change the meaning, although I noticed it still makes sense in a certain context (see other comments).

Comment: ではその点は考えが違いますね。私は「問題は水が少ないことだった」と読めると思います。ただし、この「問題は」は不要だとは思います。

Comment: あ…度々すいません、「問題は、水が少なかった」です。ちょっと拙い表現ですが。

Comment: @user4092 ああ、「問題は、お金がないです」みたいな文でしょうか。かなり乱れた文章で見ることはありますが、プロの物書きなら「問題はお金がない**こと**です」と言うべきかなーと、さすがに。（あと思いっきり回答を書き直したので変になってたらすみません）

Answer (score 3):

> 生{い}きるか死{し}ぬかの問題{もんだい}だった。
>
> 飲{の}み水{みず}が、一週間分{いっしゅうかんぶん}あるかどうかだった。

Overall, you have a good understanding of the passage.

The first sentence tells us right away that there was a rather serious issue and the second explains exactly what the degree of the problem was.

The comma in the second sentence is completely optional.  It is not needed as far as grammar.  IMHO, the author used the comma to make the sentence look more dramatic by "forcing" a short pause there.

「飲み水が」 modifies 「あるかどうか」 and not 「だった」.

The omitted topic is 「問題」 here, which is already mentioned in the first sentence.

My own TL:

> "It was a matter of life or death."
>
> "It was at the level of whether or not (our) water supply would last a week."

Answer (score 1):

## English

> (1) 生きるか死ぬかの問題だった。
> *It was a question of life or death*.
> (2) 飲み水が、一週間[分]{ぶん}あるかどうかだった。
> *It was a question of whether or not there was a week's worth of water.*

If OP thinks that "the only way I can make sense of this structure of (2) is to assume that 飲み水 is the subject of ある. I'm parsing it like this: [問題は] [飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうか] [だった] *It was a question of whether or not there was a week's worth of water*", I think OP interprets (2) as "１週間分の水があれば助かる、それより少なければ助からない *If there was a week's worth of water I would be saved and if there was water less than that I would not be saved.*"
I also interpreted it as OP did for a moment and thought that it was correct that the OP added "問題は" at the beginning of (2).

However I think it's impossible that such a sentence as (2) could exist logically under actual circumstances.
The interpretation of OP is valid only if you know that the relief team will arrive in a week or if you can reach some place where there is sufficient water within a week.
Do you really measure whether the amount of water at hand is a week's worth when you are in a situation "生きるか死ぬかの問題だった *It was a question of life or death*" as the sentence of (1) says?
The meaning of "飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうかだった" is not "It was a question whether or not there was a week's worth of drinking water" but I think "Only sure thing was that there was at most a week's worth of drinking water at hand."

As the conclusion, the whole meaning of (1) and (2) is that "It was a question of life or death. Only sure thing was that there was at most a week's worth of drinking water at hand. Nothing other than that was sure." or "It was a question that I had to live only with the amount of water worth for a week or so at hand when I was neither sure whether a relief team would come or not nor sure whether I could reach/found the place where there was plenty of water before the water at hand was consumed."

## 日本語

> (1) 生きるか死ぬかの問題だった。
> (2) 飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうかだった。

質問者は(2)を「１週間分の水があれば助かる、それより少なければ助からない」と解釈しているように思います。
私も、一瞬そのように思い、(2)の最初に質問者が「問題は」を補ったことは正解だと思いました。

しかし、どう考えてもそのような文は論理的に存在しないような気がします。
水が１週間分あれば助かるとは、１週間後に救援隊が来ることが分かっている場合あるいは、１週間あれば水のあるところにたどり着ける場合の論理です。(1)の「生きるか死ぬかの問題」である時に、水が１週間分あるかどうかを計測しますか。

「一週間分あるかどうか」は、whether or notではなく、「水が**約**一週間分ある *there is about one week's worth of water*」という意味だと思います。

結論として、
(2)を含む全体の意味は、「手許{てもと}にあるのは、水が約１週間分の分量あるという事実だけだ。これだけで果たして生き延びられるだろうか。救援隊が来るかどうか（、あるいは水のあるところにたどり着けるかどうか）は全くわからない。それが問題である。」

(2)の文の冒頭に言葉を足すなら、「問題は」ではなく「手許｛てもと｝にあるのは」だと思う。

Comment: どうしても一週間手元にある水で生き延びないといけないという状態は全然ありえると思いますよ。しかも質問者はその二つの文章が同じ文脈のものであるか、それとも全く関係なくただ同じ文型の例だるかをハッキリとしていません。
いずれにせよ(2)の文章を英訳すると、やはり「It was a matter of whether or not there was a week's worth of water」となるでしょう。

Comment: @derpda:どうしても一週間手元にある水で生き延びないといけないという状態は私もあり得ると思います。しかしそれはそういう状況があるのであって、言葉として表現した時に論理的にあり得る文としては別です。「飲み水が、一週間分あるかどうかだった」とは、どういう意味ですか。私は(1)抜きで、「飲み水が、たかだか一週間分の分量であった」だと思いますが、「飲み水が、一週間分あるかそれともないかということであった。」という言葉が存在する状況とはどのような状況ですか。私は、「一週間手元にある水で生き延びないといけないという状態」の説明とは結びつかないように思います。

Comment: 個人的には「1週間よりも長く自力で生き延びないといけない（例えば次の定期便が1か月後にしか来ない）状況だけど、せいぜい手許には1週間生きられるかどうか程度の水しかない（だから困っているんだよ）」という状況ではと思っています。「It was a matter of whether or not there was a week's worth of water」ってその状況で使える英文でしょうか？　「1週間分の水があるのかないのか」の問題ではなく、「水がともかく足りない」という問題のような気がするのですが。

Comment: @derpda:「飲み水が、一‌​週間分あるかそれともないかということが問題であ‌​った。It was a matter of whether or not there was a week's worth of water」と言う表現が許されるのは、例えば遭難者ではなく、救助する側や遭難者の家族の側です。「あの人たち、水はどうかしら、食料はどうかしら。１週間分持っていればいいのだ、それも分からないし、とっても心配だ。」

Comment: ああ…まあ状況によってはあり得ますか…「救助は、ちょうど1週間後に来ることが分かった。今ここにある物資を確かめてみた。食料も燃料も電池も十分にあった。しかし水だけがない。生きるか死ぬかの問題だった。飲み水が一週間分あるかどうかだった。それだけが生き残るための鍵だ。もっと必死に水を探してみた…」という状況は一応作れますね。かなり苦しいし、こんな話ならそもそも質問をされない気がしますけど…。

Comment: @mackygoo I really appreciate your efforts at answering but I'm afraid my Japanese is poor and I find your answers very difficult to understand.

Comment: @mackygoo I too honestly have some trouble following your explanations. Maybe try and use a little more simplified Japanese! =)
But maybe we can agree that both interpretations are possible and it ends up depending on the (unknown) context. Although I do think that my interpretation is maybe the more obvious one.

Comment: @user3856370: I added an English version.